# File upload problem for each record of the table

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core

In a list, I want to send a file for each record, but only the first record is sent.
I think the problem is with id.It only sends the file of the first record, but the send button does not work for the second record.please help

In a list, I want to send a file for each record, but only the first record is sent.
I think the problem is with id.It only sends the file of the first record, but the send button does not work for the second record.please help

```
@{
    var count3 = 0;
}
        <td>


            <div class="modal fade mt-5 " id="Edit5@(count3)">
                <div class="modal-dialog  modal-lg">
                    <div class="modal-content">


                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h6 class="modal-title Bold ">آپلود رسید پرداخت</h6>

                        </div>


                        <div class="modal-body">

                             <form asp-controller="UserTax" asp-action="SabtTaxParvaned" method="post">
                            <table class="table table-bordered text-sm ">

                                <thead class="text-center">

                                    <tr style="background-color:#416992; color: white">

                                        <th>آپلود رسید پرداخت</th>
                                        <th>عملیات</th>



                                    </tr>

                                </thead>

                                <tr>


                                        <td>
                                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
                                                <div>
                                                    <label asp-for="FilePath2" class="btn btn-outline-info">
                                                        انتخاب فایل
                                                        <span class="oi oi-file h5 text-dark"></span>

                                                    </label>
                                                    <span class="text-center mt-2" id="spnImageCartMlie" style="color: black;font-size: 12px"></span>

                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                    <input type="button" onclick="UploadImage()" value="آپلود فایل" class="btn btn-outline-danger " id="btnUpLoad" />

                                                    <div id="divmessage" class="text-center hidden m-2"></div>


                                                </div>
                                                <input id="newCartMlieImagePathName" name="newCartMlieImagePathName" hidden />
                                                <input id="FilePath2" asp-for="FilePath2" type="file" required class="d-none">
                                            </div>

                                            <div class=" ">
                                                <div class="progress">
                                                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped
                                                        active" role="progressbar"
                                                         aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:0%">
                                                        0%
                                                    </div>

                                                </div>
                                            </div>


                                        </td>
                                        <td><button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">ثبت</button></td>
                                </tr>


                                <tr>

                            </table>
                            </form>

                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">بستن</button>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
                  
            </div>

                             
        </td>

<script>
    $("#FilePath2").change(function () {
        var filename = this.files[0].name;
        $("#spnImageCartMlie").html(filename);
    });
</script>


<script>
    var UploadImage = function () {
        var data = new FormData;
        var file = $("#FilePath2").get(0);

        var files = file.files;
        //کنترل سایز فایل
        if (files[0].size >= 5120000) {
            $("#spnImageCartMlie").removeClass('hidden');
            $("#spnImageCartMlie").text('حجم فایل بیش از 500 کیلوبایت است');
            $("#spnImageCartMlie").css("color", "red");
            return false;
        }


        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            data.append('filearray', files[i]);
            data.append('filesize', files[i].size);
        }
        data.append('path', "img\\mostandat\\");

        $.ajax({
            xhr: function () {
                var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();

                xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
                    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                        percentComplete = parseInt(percentComplete * 100);

                        $('.progress-bar').width(percentComplete + '%');
                        $('.progress-bar').html(percentComplete + '%');

                    }
                }, false);

                return xhr;
            },
            url: '@Url.Action("UploadImageFile", "UserTax")',
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        }).done(function (result) {
            if (result.status == "success") {

                toastr.success('فایل با موفقیت آپلود شد', {
                    timeOut: 2000,
                    closeButton: true,
                });


                $("#newCartMlieImagePathName").val(result.imagename);
            }

        }).fail(function (result) {
            if (result.status != "success") {
                toastr.warning('در حین آپلود مشکلی بوجود آمد', {
                    timeOut: 2000,
                    closeButton: true,
                });

            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have multiple records, each with its own file upload button and input as well, using the same ID for all of them, it's going to cause conflicts - **browser is expecting IDs to be unique within a page**, so when a script tries to access an element by its ID, **it's always going to retrieve the first one it finds, which is the reason why only the first record's upload works**

To solve this, you would dynmically assign unique IDs, you can use count3 for this purpose, but make sure to increment it for each record and you need to update javascript functions to work with these dynamic ids.

```
    @{
        var count3 = 0;
    }
    ...
    @foreach (var item in yourCollection) {  // Assuming you have a collection of items
        <td>
            <div class="modal fade mt-5" id="Edit5@(count3)">
                ...
                <input id="FilePath2_@(count3)" name="FilePath2" type="file" required class="d-none">
                ...
                <input type="button" onclick="UploadImage('@(count3)')" value="آپلود فایل" class="btn btn-outline-danger" id="btnUpLoad_@(count3)" />
                ...
            </div>
        </td>
        count3++;
    }
```

For the JavaScript part:

1. Change event for file input like this:

```
    $("[id^=FilePath2_]").change(function () {
        var idSuffix = this.id.split('_')[1];
        var filename = this.files[0].name;
        $("#spnImageCartMlie_" + idSuffix).html(filename);
    });
```

2. UploadImage function:

```
    var UploadImage = function (idSuffix) {
        var fileInputId = "#FilePath2_" + idSuffix;
        var data = new FormData();
        var file = $(fileInputId).get(0);
        ...
        // Rest of your logic
    }
```